# Can C# 8 new switch replace a code block containing multiple ? : ? : expressions?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-8.0

Here's an example of what I am doing now:

```
return
    shpc == 0 ? "Currently, based on your selection below, you have not yet identified any hidden cards in your card deck." :
    shpc == 1 ? "Currently, based on your selection below, you have one hidden card in your card deck." :
                $"Currently, based on your selection below, you have {shpc} hidden cards in your card deck. These will not be visible.";
```

The code words but not having much knowledge of what was added to switch I wonder if this could also be done with a switch expression?

Comment: you can replace this with a "classic" switch, no need for the new fancy features of c#8 switch

Comment: @GianPaolo the switch expression is far cleaner and easier to use than a `switch` statement with lots of `return`s or direct variable assignments in the case blocks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
return shpc switch 
{
    0 => "Currently, based on your selection below, you have not yet identified any hidden cards in your card deck.",
    1 => "Currently, based on your selection below, you have one hidden card in your card deck.",
    _ => $"Currently, based on your selection below, you have {shpc} hidden cards in your card deck. These will not be visible."
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Definitely:

```
return shpc switch 
{
    0 => "Currently, based on your selection below, you have not yet identified any hidden cards in your card deck.",
    1 => "Currently, based on your selection below, you have one hidden card in your card deck.",
    _ => $"Currently, based on your selection below, you have {shpc} hidden cards in your card deck. These will not be visible."
};
```